# Shopware 6 with Mailchimp

Tags: mailchimp, shopware

I installed the Mailchimp Plugin in Shopware 6 and created a SMTP connection in the mailer.
On the server itselfe i created a redirect from http to https and in my sales channel i set up the domain with https://my-url.de.
But the Plugin always responds with:

```
CHECK                               STATUS
Base URL                            http://763.dev-weblabels.de
HTTPS enabled?                      false
HTTPS Connection valid              false
HTTPS Connection Message            HTTPS is disabled!
Shop API reachable under APP_URL    true
Shop API Status                     Shop is reachable
Shop API Token available            false

Your current shop configuration does not allow you to use the app.
Please have: SSL enabled, your main domain set correctly!
Please try again when your configuration is fixed.
```

I have tried reinstalling the plugin and changed URL redirect but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Are you talking about this plugin? https://store.shopware.com/mailc14137522715f/mailchimp-for-shopware-6.html - are you trying to use the self-hosted version or the shopware-cloud app? How did you install the plugin? Can you check whether your `APP_URL` in the file `.env` does not use https:// ?

Comment: Sry for the missing information.
Everything you said was correct for my case and the change worked.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the APP_URL in the `.env` file :-)